# AngularJS Google Maps Click Event not firing in ios devices ipad and iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, google-maps, ipad

I have integrated google maps API with my app for autocomplete suggestions, it is working fine on my laptop(Ubuntu) all browsers as well. However, recently I have tested with iPad and iPhone it doesn't work. I'm unable to click the suggested places. I'm using AngularJS and my code snippet is below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form name="searchForm" ng-submit="fillInAddress()">
            <div class="input-group well">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autocomplete" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city" 
                onFocus="geolocate()" required />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ladda="ldloading.slide_left" data-style="slide-left" data-spinner-color="#000000"
                        ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 var placeSearch, autocomplete;

  function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode']});
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    locationfilter.lat=place.geometry.location.lat();
    locationfilter.lon=place.geometry.location.lng();
    $scope.getOrders($scope.reportParams,locationfilter);
  }

  $scope.getOrders = function(pagination, locationfilter) {
    $scope.working = true;
    sliveorders
      .getLocOrders(pagination, locationfilter)
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.Orders=res.data;
        $scope.totalItems=res.total;  
        $scope.working = false;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Location search err:', err);
        $scope.working = false;
      });  
  }

  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  };
  initAutocomplete();
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or plnkr to reproduce your problem? Is the `button` with `type"submit"` not working? Means: `ng-submit` is not working?

Comment: yes the button with type="submit" is not working remember it is working in laptop/desktop browsers it just doesn't work on ios devices(except laptop) such as ipad,iphone

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or plnkr to reproduce your problem? I

Comment: not now actually but will do in some time and will update here

Comment: Are you using ngTouch?

Comment: @Kannan, Have you tried this collection of directives: ngmap, https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

Comment: @RandyCasburn Nope

Comment: @lin sorry for the delay bro was out of town check this out https://codepen.io/kannant14/pen/LeVpLg

Comment: @beaver it is for angular 2+ bro am using AngularJS(1.x)

Comment: @kannan no, it is both for AngularJS (http://ngmap.github.io/) and Angular2 (https://github.com/ng2-ui/map), check better

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working (tested on iPad with IoS 9.2) example using [ng-map](https://ngmap.github.io/), an AngularJS library for Google Maps.

```js
angular.module("app", ['ngMap']).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, NgMap) {
    var vm = this;
    //vm.types = "['geocode']";
    vm.types = "['establishment']";
    vm.usebounds = false;
    
    vm.placeChanged = function() {
        vm.place = this.getPlace();
        console.log('location', vm.place.geometry.location);
        vm.map.setCenter(vm.place.geometry.location);
    }
    
    vm.geolocate = function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
       console.log("geolocate");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var geolocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          console.log("position", position);
          if (vm.usebounds) {
            vm.mybounds = {
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            };
          }
          vm.map.setCenter(geolocation);  
        });
      }
    };
    
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
       vm.map = map;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
      Enter your city: <br/>
      <input places-auto-complete size=80
        ng-model="vm.address"
        component-restrictions="{country:'us'}"
        types="{{types}}"
        ng-focus="vm.geolocate()"
        strict-bounds="true"
        circle-bounds="{{vm.mybounds}}"
        on-place-changed="vm.placeChanged()" /> <br/>
     <input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="vm.usebounds">use bounds
        <br/>
      <div ng-show="vm.place">
        Address = {{vm.place.formatted_address}} <br/>
        Location: {{vm.place.geometry.location}}<br/>
      </div>
      <hr>
      bounds: {{vm.mybounds}}
    </div>
    <ng-map></ng-map>
</div>
```

And here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/mu5u71sg/

Answer (score 1):

The `place_changed` event is hampered on IOS. The fix is to wrap the `placed_changed` event inside a normal `click` event that then dispatches the `place_changed` event like this:

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete')
  .addEventListener('click', e=>autocomplete.dispatchEvent('place_changed'));
```

so `initAutoComplete()` becomes:

```
  function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode']});
    document.getElementById('autocomplete')
       .addEventListener('click', e=>autocomplete.dispatchEvent('place_changed'));
  }
```